# how to get rid of spaces between parent navbar links

Tags: html, css, navbar

I was just wondering how to get rid of the spaces between my parent navbar links (and at the start of the navbar) so they are touching and you cannot see the background behind it.
Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/maRw6/

here is what I mean: !http://imgur.com/woIuw1r

Here is the code:

```
 <html>
<head>
<style>
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 9pt;
}
ul#navmenu li {
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-right: 0px;
display:inline-block;
}
#navmenu ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
white-space:nowrap;
}
#page1 {
text-align: center;
}
ul#navmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 202px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
border: 1px solid #777777;
border-top: 2px solid #777777;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-face: Arial;
float: left;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;

}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
margin-top: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
margin-left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
background-color: grey;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
background-color: red;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 66px;
left: 203px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
display: block;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
display: block;
}
.darrow {
font-size: 10pt;
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
right: 20px;
}
#navmenu {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;

}
.rarrow {
font-size: 11pt;
position: absolute;
top: 73px;
right: 20px;
}
ul#navmenu {
width:100% !important;
}
#page1 .link1 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
#page2 .link2 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
#page3 .link3 {
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
border-left: 0px solid red;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
max-width: 1440px;
height: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#box2 {
height: 1000px;
width: 1024px;
background-color: #FFFE8E;
align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
}
#boxinbox1 {
width: 100%;

background-color: #E51837;
}

ul#navmenu li ul li
{

display:block;

}
}

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E51837">

    <div id="box2">
        <div id="page1">
            <div id="boxinbox1"><img src="Logo1.gif"  height="200px"><br>            .  .             <img src="text.gif" height="100px"></div>
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="dropdown1.html" class="link1">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="dropdown2.html" class="link2">hyperlink 2</a>                                      .              <font color="white">
<span class="darrow">&#9660;</font>
                    </span>
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4</a><span class="darrow">                .  .              <font color="white">&#9660;               

 </font></span> 
                    <ul class="sub1">
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3</a><span class="rarrow">
<font color="white">&#9654;</font></span>

                            <ul class="sub2">
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
<a href="dropdown3.html" class="link3">hyperlink 4.3.3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,this is a hack to remove the spaces between `<li>` elements.

Just add a `margin-right:-2px;`

```
 ul#navmenu li {
        width: 202px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        margin-right: -2px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Dont forget to adjust the first and last 'li' element to align :)

Answer (score 2):

usually spaces between elements are caused by the elements being inline block. Try making them  (the li elements) block elements and floating them to the left. Then, make the ul inline block and you'll be able to align the ul with text-align property really easily. That's what I usually do anyway, but basically the extra space is caused by your elements having white space between them. Chris Coyier gives a fairly extensive list of the ways you can fight this.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/